# Loading film through first spindle

Tags: film

It was my first time loading film in but after watching more videos now i think i have done it wrong. I fed the film through the first spindle. Is it meant to go in the second spindle? The camera is working and the shutter numbers are going up.

Comment: I still regularly shoot film with a dozen or more different cameras and don't understand what you mean with 'first spindle' and 'second spindle'. Care to explain?

Comment: Movie or stills camera? Which camera model? Any details would be helpful.